# Excel Spreadsheet Formula for Calculating Dollar Amount based on Time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Part of my job has me calculate media values (i.e., what we must pay a broadcaster
to broadcast our (commercial/infomercial) content)
based on a 30 second average we receive from a third party application. 
We round dollar amounts to the nearest whole cent,
and we round down the nearest increment of 5 seconds.

Here's an example of how we currently calculate: We have a media value of $1,000 per 30 seconds, and our segment airs for 4 minutes and 25 seconds. We multiply that 30 second value by 8 to get our 4 minute media value. Then we divide the 30 second value by 6 to get the value for every 5 seconds. Then we would multiply that 5 second dollar value by 5 to get the value for 25 seconds. Then finally we add those two values together.

> 1000   × 8 = 8000.00     — 4 minute value
>
> 1000   ÷ 6 = 166.67     — Value per 5 seconds
>
> 166.67 × 5 =  833.35     — Value for 25 seconds
>
> 8000.00 + 833.35 = 8833.35  — Total value for 4 minutes and 25 seconds

I know there must be a way to program an Excel sheet to calculate the exact value we want. I'm not too savvy with the program, but I figure a cell can hold the 30 second value, which could be divided by 6 to get the average for 5 seconds. Then in another cell have the clip to our nearest rounded 5 second increment in mm:ss format. Then have the values multiplied and have a final cell with our answer. Am I off track, or is this possible? Again, any help appreciated!

Comment: The numbers in your example don't match up (how can the value for 30 seconds be 166.67 and the value for 25 seconds be 833.35?) can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1412195/edit) to fix it? It would also be useful to know what your actual data looks like in Excel

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad My mistake, that 166.67 is the value for 5 seconds. Also, we don't use Excel for this data at all. We calculate on paper then put into a word document for those who need to know.

Comment: (1) Please verify my edit. If I got your meaning wrong, please fix it.  (2) Since you say “we round down the nearest increment of 5 seconds”, your question would be clearer if you gave an example of how to handle a value that isn’t already a multiple of 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Put the cost (in dollars per thirty seconds) in cell A2.

Put the segment duration (in minutes, so 4:25 would be entered as `=4+25/60` in cell B2.

Then, in cell C2, enter this formula:

```
=B2*2*A2
```

That first multiplies the segment duration by 2, to get it in thirty-second units, then multiplies by A2, which is the cost per thirty-second unit.

You can then format C2 to the nearest whole cent.

(I assume that you don't need the intermediate results, and that they were included in your example as a way to describe your current manual process.)

[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

#### Time Calculations

This formula does not do intermediate rounding but does use the FLOOR (round down) the seconds to the nearest 5. If the media value cell is `B5` then:

B5`=$A$2*FLOOR(A5,TIME(0,0,5))/TIME(0,0,30)`

- `$A$2` is the Cost per 30 seconds
- `A5` is the duration of the media as a Time formatted cell `mm:ss`

The same duration but with the OP Intermediate Rounding applied.

B6=`=A2 * INT(A5/TIME(0,0,30))  +  ROUND(A2/6,2) * INT( MOD(A5,TIME(0,0,30)) / TIME(0,0,5))`

[image]